# How many different whole numbers are factors of number $2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

The question is:

> How many different whole numbers are factors of number $2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13$?

My answer to this question is $63$ but the right answer is $64$. I don't know why it is $64$? I need some assistance.

Comment: Are you including 1 in your answer?

Comment: Have you used the term  $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}$ or somerhing similar? 1 should be part of the factors.

Comment: @Kyler- I thought about including 1 but I didn't do it because i was a little doubtful about it..

Comment: @calcullus- I don't know what the summation means, but I will include the 1.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got the right answer

Comment: @DanielJoseph Have you included 1?

Comment: @calcullus- Yup

Comment: @DanielJoseph I suspect that 1 is part of the  factors.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @callculus42-Yes that '1' is also a factor

Comment: @N.F.Taussig-Thanks man....for the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the solution as well by omitting the factor 1. One unique whole number is if you multiply all 6 primes. The corresponding sequence is $2,3,5,7,11,13$. So we have one sequence. The corresponding binomial coefficient is $\binom{6}{0}=1$

Then we can remove one of the 6 factors. This can be done with all 6 prime factors. The number of sequences is $\binom{6}{1}=5$.

Next we remove two factors. The resulting sequences are: $ 5,7,11,13\quad 3,7,11,13\quad 3,5,11,13\quad 3,5,7,13\quad 3,5,7,11$

$2,7,11,13\quad 2,5,11,13\quad 2,5,7,13\quad 2,5,7,11\quad 2,3,11,13$

$ 2,3,7,13\quad 2,3,7,11\quad 2,3,5,13\quad 2,3,9,11\quad 2,3,7,9$

Basically we two kinds of elements: The removed elements (x) and the remaining (a) elements. Then the number of such sequences is $\binom{6}{2}=15$.

We can go on like this by removing $3, 4$ and $5$ factors. Then the sum is

$$\sum_{i=1}^6 \binom{6}{i}=2^6-1=63$$

The result is easy to evaluate due the binomial theorem, see  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

One point of view is that $i=6$ is not possible since we would remove all prime factors. On the other hand they don't talk about prime factors, but factors only. Then the number 1 is valid and we obtain $63+1=64$ different numbers.

Comment: Removing all prime factors gives you the product $2^0 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^0 \cdot 7^0 \cdot 11^0 \cdot 13^0 = 1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, I've edited my answer and I've included you thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the comments, you overlooked the one.

Here is a method that can be generalized:

Each factor of $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$ has the form $2^{a_1}3^{a_2}5^{a_3}7^{a_4}11^{a_5}13^{a_6}$, where $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6 \in \{0, 1\}$.  Since there are two possible choices for each of the six exponents, there are $2^6 = 64$ possible factors of $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$.

Comment: Yes, I thought about the 1 once I checked my solution was wrong..

Comment: But you also included the chance where you take no factors....

Comment: If all the exponents are zero, the product is equal to $1$, which is a factor of $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$.